# What is the use of Applicative/Monad instances for Sum and Product?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

My understanding of `Sum` and `Product` newtypes is that they serve as monoidial wrappers for numeric types. I would understand `Functor` instance on them, but why there are also `Applicative`, `Monad` any many other seemingly useless instances? I understand that they are mathemathically OK (isomorphic to `Identity` modad, right?) But what is the use case? If there is an `Applicative Sum` instance, for example, I would expect to encounter a value of type `Sum (a -> b)` somewhere. I can't imagine where this could possibly be useful.

Comment: I agree, these instances seem to make no sense whatsoever. Clear case of “because we can”.

Comment: I don't have access to GHCi right now, but is it possible that they could be used for doing something like `x :: Sum Int; x = do { 1; 2; 3; 4; 5 }`?

Comment: @bheklilr It "works", and returns `Sum 5` since `Sum` is the identity monad.

Comment: It seems that it's possible to do something similar: `x :: Sum Int; x = do {Sum 1; Sum 2}`) and get the actual sum with -XRebindableSyntax  by saying `(>>) = mappend
` https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-06-rebindable-syntax.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Such instances are convenient for lifting arbitrary functions to work on things that happen to currently be living inside a `Sum` or `Product`. For example, one might imagine wanting to do some bitwise operations on something that is nevertheless more convenient in a `Sum` than bare; then `liftA2 (.&.) :: Sum Int -> Sum Int -> Sum Int` (for example).

One could also provide this operation by giving a `Bits` instance for `Sum`, but generalizing that technique would require the implementors of `Sum` to predict every operation one might ever want to do, which seems like a tall order. Providing `Applicative` and `Monad` instances give a once-and-for-all translation for users to lift any function they like -- including ones the implementors of `Sum` did not predict being useful.

Comment: Yes, but that's arguably an abuse of the `Applicative` class. It's much better to use [`Iso` combinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html) for this purpose.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Can you say carefully what is better about the `Iso` combinators? Naively, they look like a strange tradeoff: it's a very heavy dependency (certainly not one that should be rolled into base), and the syntax for lifting two- or more-argument functions looks verbose compared to a single application of `liftA2`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, when I look at `au` and `auf`, mine eyes glazeth over.

Comment: @DanielWagner well, I didn't particularly suggest using `lenses` to accomplish `liftA2 (.&.)` on `Sum`. That is certainly not sensible. What I actually meant is that it doesn't do much good to keep `Sum` wrapped values around at all and combine them like that – these newtypes are intended so you can inject them into a single algorithm that works on monoids but that you want to use with numbers, but not to actually get an result of type `Sum Int`. In other words, I understand `Sum` more as a tag you can pass to functions to explain what to do with numbers, not as an actual type constructor.

Comment: ...hence I also don't find it reasonable to give them any instances at all apart from the `Monoid` one which these newtypes are all about. — The iso combinators make it easier to “tag-wrap” a number into a `Sum` in for a single operation, without needing to manually wrap and unwrap again. If `lens` is to much of a dependency you can also use them [from the original package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-0.2/docs/Control-Newtype.html).

Answer (score 3):

Values like this typically result from partial application of binary operators. Assuming `Functor` and `Applicative` instances like

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Monoid

instance Functor Sum where
    fmap f (Sum x) = Sum (f x)

instance Applicative Sum where
    pure = Sum
    (Sum f) <*> (Sum x) = Sum (f x)
```

then you can see how a value of `Sum (a -> b)` would arise.

```
> :t (*) <$> (Sum 5)
(*) <$> (Sum 5) :: Num a => Sum (a -> a)

> (*) <$> (Sum 5) <*> (Sum 10)
Sum {getSum = 50}
```

Comment: `Sum 5 * Sum 10` also works, because of the `Num` instance.